# How to disable only screen recording in native android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I want to enable screenshot but want's to disable the screen recording in android application.

I tried the following code.

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

But this code disable both screen shot and screen record. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing in the OS that would do that, it's all or nothing.  Also, if you allow screenshots you can take videos by just taking a series of screenshots quickly enough